# Expected number of repetitions coin tosses

Tags: algorithms, education

Suppose we flip a coin n-times. By a series of repetitions we mean successive tosses in which the same side of the coin lands (heads or tails each time). For example, in HHHTTHTH ( => 8) there are 5 repetition sequences.

> HHH-TT-HTH -> HHH are 3 and TT are 2, summary there is 5 repetitions

What is the expected number of repetition sequences for n-flips ??
How to resolve this, i was trying draw it as probability tree and calculate summary of probability successes but i didnt get anything with any sense.

**/// I updated this post**

I tried to solve this after your advices, but I think I do something wrong

**Step 1**
We toss a symetric coin so chances for H or T are equal = 0.5

Let:
$ a_n $ - number of repetion sequences for n flips

In first toss we have:
$ a_1=1 $

For next tosses $ n+1 $ we have got 50% chances to continue sequence from $n$

As formula it's $ a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+1}{2} $

or 50% to beginn new series ofrepetitions:
$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}*1$

Let's write both together as recurent formula:
$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}*\left(a_n+1\right)+\frac{1}{2}*1$

After simplify:
$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$

**Try proof that**

Calculate this for n flips:

$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$

$a_n=\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$

$a_{n-1}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$

⋮

$a_2=\frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$

$a_1=1$

After substituting and calculating the above equations, we get the following:

$a_n=1+\frac{n-1}{2}\ = \frac{n+1}{2} $

And my question is  whether the above provisions are OK and how to proof this? Math iteration, induction? I don't know how to do this proof.

Comment: "For example, in HHHTTHTH ( = 8) there are 5 repetition sequences" : please explain this.  I count only 3 positions where the coin flip is the same as the coin flip right before it.

Comment: @user2661923: As assumed in raj's answer, it seems that "repetition sequences" is used here in the sense that "run" is conventionally used: A maximal string of equal letters.

Comment: Could anyone help me solve this, step by step? I'd be grateful

Answer (score 2):

Try induction: if $a_n$ is the expected number of repetition sequences after $n$ coin tosses then it's clear that $a_1 = 1$. Furthermore if we toss another coin, the probability this is part of a 'new' repetition sequence is precisely $1/2$ (since this is just the event we get a different toss to the previous one). Thus $a_{n+1} = a_n + 1/2$ implying $a_n = 1+\frac{n-1}{2}$.

Comment: Induction seems a bit of an overkill here. There are $n-1$ points between flips, and each starts a new run (in addition to the first run) with probability $\frac12$, so by linearity of expectation the expected number of runs is $1+\frac{n-1}2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please help me write these equations. I'd be very grateful